# executable comments in OCaml

Tags: haskell, ocaml

In Haskell, there is this handy feature where one can write a special comment, and it will be evaluated in the context of the file.

Is there a similar feature in the OCaml ecosystem ?

---

Details in Haskell : [image]

When I click "refresh", the expression `evalT2 IType ex1` will be (re)evaluated, and its output printed below

---

In OCaml, I would do something along

```
(** cd /ml/compil
    dune utop
    utop # #require "compil";;
    utop # Compil__Compil_intf.x;;
    - : int option = Some 256
    *)
```

Comment: That is not a Haskell feature. It's a feature of an IDE or similar graphical environment.

Comment: Specifically it looks like Visual Studio Code. Probably any language that supports the LSP has this feature, if you just put `>>>` at the beginning of a comment.

Comment: @Carl It still pertains to the haskell ecosystem. questions on stack overflow don't necessarily relate to language as a specification, but to programming in general (I guess?)

Comment: @amalloy I wish..

Comment: This feature was first seen (afaik) in the [dante](https://github.com/jyp/dante) whose purpose is to support Haskell development in emacs. Now visual studio LSP has picked up this great feature.

Comment: @nicolas My point was simply that it's not a question about Haskell or O'Caml. It's a question about tooling available. It's better to raise the question with a more precise statement, something like "This tool I'm using has this feature for Haskell. Is there a similar tool for O'Caml?"

Comment: @Carl Sure, but we can always go further in that direction. For instance, what most people call Haskell here is actually GHC. When I write "in haskell", I mean "in haskell ecosystem" and that's congruent with the analogy mentioning ".... in the ocaml **ecosystem**". Those two tools (VS and emacs w Dante) might not be the only ones having this great feature and they are quite popular. Same with cabal or stack "in haskell"... I doubt anyone imagined it's a feature of the language itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, to my knowledge, no assimilable functionality "included" in the language, however, it is possible to build interactive documents using [Notebook Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/), which has an [OCaml kernel](https://akabe.github.io/ocaml-jupyter/).

In addition, during the writing of the [second version of Real World OCaml](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/), a tool, [**mdx**](https://github.com/realworldocaml/mdx) was designed to simplify the integration of code fragments into textual content, making these fragments executable and approaching the "literate" approach to programming.

The tool (mdx) integrates quite well with [Dune](https://dune.build/) (OCaml's canonical build-system) and allows "unit test-like" execution of Markdown documents and is being integrated seamlessly into [ODoc](https://github.com/ocaml/odoc) (OCaml's new documentation generator). You can see some examples on this project which uses mdx to make the examples executable and share the test suite: [Preface Guide](https://github.com/xvw/preface/tree/master/guides).